# Objective C iOS pre load views

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar based application with 3 tabs (views). How would I, either in the app delegate or in the first tab that is loaded, would I load the entire contents of the other 2 views in the background?

Right now I have a webView in each of the views in question. Part of my problem is that they are loaded in the viewDidLoad but cause a wait with a blank screen

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is not that clear to me.. So I you have 3 `UIViewController` (or subclasses of them) contained in an `UITabBarViewController`, the way to force them to load their view is call the `-view` property on each of them in the AppDelegate rich before you add to the UITabbarViewController instance. Something like this:

```
UIViewController * myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mynib" bundle:nil];
[myViewController view];//<--here you are forcing the view to be loaded before it will be called from the tabbatviewcontroller
```

This is a way to avoid (not at all) the behavior you are experiencing...concepts of  loading in background are a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 7):

Try to:

```
viewController.view.hidden = NO;
```

for any viewController you want to pre-load and it has beeb allocated and initialized. That is, after alloc and initWithNibName:... has been done.

Comment: If i remember correctly, you can actually use any statement with `viewController.view`, and get the same effect.  I think the `view` property is probably implemented with lazy loading, so as soon as someone tries to reference it, it loads.

Comment: But this one does not require a "return" so no warnings shown! :)

Comment: This is even more important in Xcode 6 (at least when using Swift) which reports an error when not using the value of viewController.view.

Answer (score 4):

I typically use something like this:

```
if (vc.view == nil)      // force load of view
{
    NSLog(@"%s ***** ERROR: view == nil: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, vc);
}
```

**NOTE:** After calling vc.view, the view should *never* be nil -- that's a pretty serious allocation bug.